# Find angle without trigonometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

I solved the following problem using the sine law. Desired value is $\angle MAC=10°$. Can you find a geometric solution?

[image]

Comment: It seems like it is a least not solvable via algebra hence the given conditions lead to a system of four equation with four unknowns where the determinate of the  matrix of coefficients equals zero.

Comment: Trigonometry expresses relationships between the ratios of various lengths within a right triangle. Any triangle can be broken up into some combination of right triangles. In principle any statement in trigonometry has a corresponding expression in solely geometric terms.

Comment: I thought the Sine Law For Triangles $was$ geometry.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use the following. Consider a regular 9-gon $I_1I_2\ldots I_9$ with center $O$, and find your picture by setting $A=O$, $B=I_3$ and $C=I_5$. Then note that $M$ is the intersection of diagonals $I_1I_5$ and $I_3I_6$.

Comment: This looks like a great idea! But I don't see how it reduces the difficulties!

Comment: @Ghartal I guess you can consider images of $M$ under isometries which preserve the 9-gon: there are 18 of them: 9 rotations and 9 symmetries. This should be a regular 18-gon implying that the central angle is 20, so your angle is 10.

Answer (score 3):

Let's go another way around.

Let $M'$ be such that $\angle M'CA = \angle M'AC = 10^{\circ}$ and let $D$ be a reflection of $C$ across line $AM'$. Then $AM' = CM' = DM'$ and a triangle $ABD$ is equlateral (since $AD = AC = AB$ and $\angle BAD = 60^{\circ}$). So $ABM'$ and $DBM'$ are congruent so $\angle DBM' = 30^{\circ}$

[image]

Now, since $A$ is a center of circle around through $B,D$ and $C$ we have also $$\angle DBC = {1\over 2}\angle DAC = 10^{\circ}$$
so $\angle CBM' = 20^{\circ}$ and thus $M'=M$.

Comment: Did knowing the answer help you find this solution? 
It's beautiful! I really enjoyed it.

Comment: Yes, but you can find this answer easly by drawing.

Comment: First idea was to rotate $A$ around $B$ for $-60$ to $D$, but didn't get anywhere. Perhaps you can try.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it.